# Is it possible to use generic constraints based on attributes rather than types?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I'm trying to write a class that will be in charge of persisting application options. Since the options need to be persisted the values that I'm sent must be serialisable.

Initially I thought I've be able to write a method with a signature like this:

```
Public Sub SaveOption(Of T As ISerializable)(ByVal id As String, ByVal value As T)
```

or if you prefer C#:

```
public void SaveOption<T>(string id, T value) where T : ISerializable
```

In principle this would be fine, but what about types that have the `<Serializable>` attribute? The most notable example of this is System.String, it does not implement `ISerializable`, but clearly it is a type that I should be able to save.

So, is there a way that I can restrict which types are allowed into a method at compiletime, based on their attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have overloads for the other types - taking your string example:

```
public void SaveOption(string id, string value)
```

However; serializability is... tricky; I expect you're going to have to check this at runtime.

Comment: I could add overloads for a few system types, but there are a large number of other types that I need to support that don't implement the interface. I guess I'll have to check stuff at run time, which is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

An attribute constraint wouldn't achieve much, since an attribute doesn't generally offer any guarantees at compile time, they're information for the runtime rather than the compiler.

In the serialization case, the `[Serializable]` attribute is only an indicator that you can *attempt* serialization at runtime, while `ISerializable` guarantees that you can serialize it, because you can definitely call `GetObjectData` and it's the class's problem to ensure that that does the right thing.

For example, I can have

```
[Serializable]
class GoodClass
{
    public object Property { get; set; }
}

class BadClass
{
}
```

but `GoodClass` is really no better than `BadClass`, because I can do

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();

GoodClass obj = new GoodClass();
f.Serialize(ms, obj); // OK

obj.Property = new BadClass();
f.Serialize(ms, obj); // BOOM
```

**EDIT:** Attributes also aren't inherited, so the compiler can't be sure that the object passed at runtime will still have the attribute you demanded:

```
class NotSoGoodClass : GoodClass // No [Serializable] attribute
{
}

...

SaveOption<GoodClass>( "id", new NotSoGoodClass() ) // oops
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. :(

Ah, no, actually in C# 4.0 they've introduced code contracts. That should work here.

Example from this link: [CLR 4.0: Code Contracts](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018170333/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/11/07/clr-4.0-code-contracts.aspx)

```
public void BuyMoreStuff(Item[] cart, ref Decimal totalCost, Item i)
{       
    CodeContract.Requires(totalCost >=0);
    CodeContract.Requires(cart != null);
    CodeContract.Requires(CodeContract.ForAll(cart, s => s != i));

    CodeContract.Ensures(CodeContract.Exists(cart, s => s == i);
    CodeContract.Ensures(totalCost >= CodeContract.OldValue(totalCost));
    CodeContract.EnsuresOnThrow<IOException>(totalCost == CodeContract.OldValue(totalCost));

    // Do some stuff
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check for this, but you're right, it will have to be done at runtime, but more formally than just throwing an exception.

```
public static byte[] SerializeObject<T>(this T obj)
{
    Contract.Requires(typeof(T).IsSerializable);
    ...
}
```