# C# Generic method as extension with where clause

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, deserialization, serializableattribute

I want to create an extension which can run only for Serializable classes.
Is there a code like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Ser
    {

    }

    public class NonSer
    {

    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        static public T f_DeepClone<T>(this T obj)
                             where T : (SerializableAttribute)
        {

            return (T) obj;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ser mc = new Ser();
            mc.f_DeepClone<Ser>();
            NonSer mc1 = new NonSer();
            mc.f_DeepClone<NonSer>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot statically check for Attributes - so either try using ISerializable or do a dynamic runtime-check in code bzw. why `this object obj` instead of `this T obj` ?

Comment: Attributes can be checked with reflection only. The class does not actually implements the attribute.

Comment: @Aphelion, There is no way to check in where clause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Attributes for Generic Constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146674/using-attributes-for-generic-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict Generic type based on attribute.

You are going to be the one using the code then you will know when an object is serializable and when it is not. There is no need for the compiler to protect you.

However if you want to check at runtime you can do:

```
static public T f_DeepClone<T>(this object obj)
{
    if(typeof(T).IsSerializable == false)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot clone non-serializable objects");

    // doing some serialization and deserialization
    return (T) obj;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Attributes in constraints I think following links will be helpful:

- [Is it possible to use generic constraints based on attributes rather than types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346485/is-it-possible-to-use-generic-constraints-based-on-attributes-rather-than-types)
- [Can you use "where" to require an attribute in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221687/can-you-use-where-to-require-an-attribute-in-c)
- [Using Attributes for Generic Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146674/using-attributes-for-generic-constraints)
- http://www.techtalkz.com/c-c-sharp/172451-generics-how-have-constraint-attribute.html (Generics: how to have a constraint on an attribute?)

However, if you can limit your domain to use ISerializable, you may do like:

```
public static class Extension<T>
{
    static public T f_DeepClone<T>(this object obj) where T: ISerializable
    {
        // doing some serialization and deserialization
        return (T) obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not every serializable class implements the interface

Answer (score 1):

You can't test for an attribute like you suggested but you could test for the interface:

```
public static class Extension
{
    static public ISerializable f_DeepClone(this ISerializable obj)
    {
        // doing some serialization and deserialization
        return (T) obj;
    }
}
```